# Problem with wp_insert_post

Tags: wp-insert-post, paypal

i'm sorry for my english.

I have a problem with the function wp_insert_post in a script.

I'm trying to create a new post when i receive a notification from paypal. Everything works fine untill i try to create a new post in the database.

This is my code:

```
<?php include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');


            // Send an email announcing "received IPN"
            $mail_From = "xxxxxx@gmail.com";
            $mail_To = "xxxxxx@gmail.com";
            $mail_Subject = "received IPN";
            $mail_Body = $req;
            mail($mail_To, $mail_Subject, $mail_Body, $mail_From);

?>
<?php

// STEP 1: read POST data

// Reading POSTed data directly from $_POST causes serialization issues with array data in the POST.
// Instead, read raw POST data from the input stream. 
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
  $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
  if (count($keyval) == 2)
     $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}
// read the IPN message sent from PayPal and prepend 'cmd=_notify-validate'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
   $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
} 
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {        
   if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) { 
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value)); 
   } else {
        $value = urlencode($value);
   }
   $req .= "&$key=$value";
}


// STEP 2: POST IPN data back to PayPal to validate

$ch = curl_init('https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

// In wamp-like environments that do not come bundled with root authority certificates,
// please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set 
// the directory path of the certificate as shown below:
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem');
if( !($res = curl_exec($ch)) ) {
    // error_log("Got " . curl_error($ch) . " when processing IPN data");
    curl_close($ch);
    exit;
}
curl_close($ch);

// STEP 3: Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly

if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {


            // Send an email announcing "enter in verified IF"
            $mail_From = "xxxxxxx@gmail.com";
            $mail_To = "xxxxxxx@gmail.com";
            $mail_Subject = "enter in verified IF";
            $mail_Body = $req;
            mail($mail_To, $mail_Subject, $mail_Body, $mail_From);

    // You should validate against these values.
            $donCause       = $_POST['item_number'];
            $txnID          = $_POST['txn_id'];
            $firstName      = $_POST['first_name'];
            $lastName       = $_POST['last_name'];
            $addressCountry = $_POST['address_country'];
            $addressCity    = $_POST['address_city'];
            $addressStreet  = $_POST['address_street'];
            $addressZip     = $_POST['address_zip'];
            $payerEmail     = $_POST['payer_email'];
            $payment_gross  = $_POST['mc_gross'];
            $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];

            if ($payment_status == 'Completed') {

                // Send an email announcing "enter in payment_status==completed"
                $mail_From = "xxxxxx@gmail.com";
                $mail_To = "xxxxxx@gmail.com";
                $mail_Subject = "enter in payment_status==completed";
                $mail_Body = $req;
                mail($mail_To, $mail_Subject, $mail_Body, $mail_From);

                // Create post object
                $my_post = array(
                    'post_title'    => $txnID,
                    'post_status'   => 'publish',
                    'post_author'   => 1,
                    'comment_status' => 'closed',
                    'ping_status' => 'closed',
                    'post_type'      => 'post_pledges',
                );
                $post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post, true );

                // Send an email announcing "after post_pledges creation"
                $mail_From = "ragazzin@gmail.com";
                $mail_To = "ragazzin@gmail.com";
                $mail_Subject = "after post_pledges creation";
                $mail_Body = $post_id;
                mail($mail_To, $mail_Subject, $mail_Body, $mail_From);

                add_post_meta($post_id, "wpl_pledge_cause", $donCause);
                add_post_meta($post_id, "wpl_pledge_transaction_id", $txnID);
                add_post_meta($post_id, "wpl_pledge_first_name", $firstName);
                add_post_meta($post_id, "wpl_pledge_last_name", $lastName);
                add_post_meta($post_id, "wpl_pledge_country", $addressCountry);
                add_post_meta($post_id, "wpl_pledge_city", $addressCity);
                add_post_meta($post_id, "wpl_pledge_address", $addressStreet);
                add_post_meta($post_id, "wpl_pledge_postal_code", $addressZip);
                add_post_meta($post_id, "wpl_pledge_email", $payerEmail);
                add_post_meta($post_id, "wpl_pledge_donation_amount", $payment_gross);
                add_post_meta($post_id, "wpl_pledge_payment_source", 'paypal');
                add_post_meta($post_id, "wpl_pledge_payment_Status", $payment_status);

            }

            // Response is VERIFIED
            // Send an email announcing the IPN message is VERIFIED
            $mail_From = "xxxxxx@gmail.com";
            $mail_To = "xxxxxxx@gmail.com";
            $mail_Subject = "VERIFIED IPN";
            $mail_Body = $req;
            mail($mail_To, $mail_Subject, $mail_Body, $mail_From);

} else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
    // IPN invalid, log for manual investigation

            // Notification protocol is NOT complete, begin error handling

            // Send an email announcing the IPN message is INVALID
             $mail_From = "xxxxxxx@gmail.com";
            $mail_To = "xxxxxxx@gmail.com";
            $mail_Subject = "INVALID IPN";
            $mail_Body = $req;
            mail($mail_To, $mail_Subject, $mail_Body, $mail_From);
}
?>
```

I read about a problem with an infinite loop and maybe it's also for me because the script doesn't go on when try to execute the function.

Have you any ideas?

Comment: Have you added a custom post type of post_pledges using [http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)? After confirming that can you post what errors or symptoms you are seeing to indicate that your create post method didn't work?

Comment: @LukeGedeon thanks for your reply. Yes, post_pledges is already registered. I checked the method didn't work from the database and also with some scripts like mail($mail_To, $mail_Subject, $mail_Body, $mail_From) that send me an email after each step of the script. I haven't received the mail defined after wp_insert_post.

Comment: have you tried determining the value of `$post_id` after you attempt to insert the post? if wp_insert_post fails, that will be an error object, you should log it to the log file and see what it contains.

Comment: i'm sorry for this reply delate. Debug.log doesn't report any error associated to ipn.php (the file that i report in the question).

Answer (score 1):

Because you mention an infinite I am guessing that you are hooked into a hook like [`save_post` that fires for `wp_insert_post()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/post.php#L3248) so if you hook your code into that your code will run then fire the same hook over and over.

To avoid that remove the action from the top of your callback:

```
remove_action('save_post','yourcallbackfunctionname');
$my_post = array(
    // ...
 );
 $post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post, true );
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. No, the script isn't a function but a IPN listener that catches and process the IPN messages sent by PayPal. I wrote about an infinite loop because the script doesn't execute any code after wp_insert_post function.

Comment: hmmm... there is code that hooks into WordPress somehow. That is going to be a function or a class, or you have a stand-alone script loading WordPress (which is almost certainly the wrong way). Post your code in context.

Comment: i edited my question with the code

Comment: I have found here [link](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/ht_ipn/) the first part of the code. I never received the mail "after post_pledges creation".